# Not able to login from admin to fiware-idm after docker installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am integrating wirecloud and fiware-idm. Installed both through docker successfully. However, after installing fiware-idm, i am not able to login from admin. username - admin@test.com password - 1234. 
Everytime it redirect it to "ip:3000/auth/login". Do I have to make any other configuration in wirecloud or fiware-idm?
Also, even after entering wrong credential, it redirects me to /auth/login and does not display any error message.

My wirecloud, fiware-idm and mysql database are in different containers. Is this can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

IdM should be deployed on production to be used by WireCloud. That is, you should configure the IDM service using public domains names, using https, and so on... Seems you are creating a local installation, so you should deploy some workarounds. Well, some of those requirements are not enforced by WireCloud, so it should be enough by ensure you use a domain name for accessing the IdM.

You can simulate having the idm server configured using public domains by adding the proper value to `/etc/hosts` (See this [link](https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992) if you are running windows), the correct value depends on how did you configured the IdM service. So, the idea is to ensure the domain used for accessing the idm resolves to the correct ip address both in the WireCloud container and from your local computer. We can provide you more detailed steps if you provide us more details about how are you launching the different containers.